# Best way to deal with borders on rollover?

Tags: css

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="span4">
       <a href="/">
          <span class="inner">Nav 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I have pipes at the side of each of my nav elements, but they do not extend to the entire height of the nav (only the text).

On rollover the pipe is still visible on the side. it's hard to explain but I have a fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v27DS/21/)

My question is, what's the best approach, so that when on rollover you hide the pipes from the user?

Comment: @IPADDRESS actually, he used border-right for the pipe

Comment: Sorry I just used the word pipe as a description, I used a border.

Comment: Wait...there is no `pipe` in your fiddle. In fact, why do you need the `.inner` span at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your css, if that is what you need, it hides all pipes when you hover one element:

```
ul:hover .inner {
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;   
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v27DS/30/

Also, if you want to hide the pipes of only the hovered element, try:

```
.inner:hover {
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;   
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v27DS/31/

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve what I'm looking to do, all pipes need to remain, I just don;t want one sticking out the side when hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sibling combinator to access the previous or next element and make its border transparent.

Read this: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```css
nav > ul > li:hover ~ li > a > span  {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

nav > ul > li:first-of-type > a > span {
   border-left: none;
}

nav > ul > li:last-of-type > a > span{
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v27DS/37/)

Comment: The the nav jumps around.

Comment: @panthro What do you mean with "jumps around"? It works perfectly no chrome.